# How to get Instagram code and Access token by server only without user login part?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I know how to get code by:

`https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=CLIENT_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=code`

However, I cannot find a way to get access token by server only.

It is blocked for all new comers and all applications lately in June 2016?

http://techcrunch.com/2015/11/17/just-instagram/

Answer (score -1):

1. You redirect user to URL you posted above.
2. User logs in (if not logged in) and grants your app permissions to access data
3. User is redirected back to URL provided in `redirect_uri` (see step 1). Also, `code` is appended to the URL.
4. You are at `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE` (which you control). Then you are able to exchange `code` for access token by querying Instagram's servers. Here is cURL command:

   `curl -F 'client_id=CLIENT_ID' \
   -F 'client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' \
   -F 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
   -F 'redirect_uri=AUTHORIZATION_REDIRECT_URI' \
   -F 'code=CODE' \
   https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token`

After you receive token for the first time, store it (if you need to access data later).

More info in official docs.: https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/